# Adding icons to many li elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

Whats the most efficient way to add different icons to a large number of li elements.
right now I'm using a separate class for now but its kind of redundant to have all theses css classes.

I'm thinking the only way to do this is using javascript jquery. Is this the only way, as css has no looping ability, or not that I know about.

Comment: Most efficient way to get answers here is to occasionally accept the answers given to you.

Comment: Do you need one on literally every `<li>`, or most of them, within a part of your page?

Comment: One unique icon on every li in my menu div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes **are** the most efficient way to add different icons to many `li` elements.

Remember to [keep all icons in one file](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites). That, plus some web-based sprites generators should save you some work.

Doing that in JavaScript would affect page load speed and overall user experience.

Comment: web-based sprites generators ? can you elaborate or a link maybe

Comment: Sure. You don't have to prepare the sprite image by yourself, you can use browser app to do that and it will generate all the classes needed for you ;-) One of many apps available: http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

Comment: very cool thanks. So using jquery looks the simplest solution to me as it makes so much sense to add a loop and your done with all the other extra CSS which is a lot. Your saying that the page would take a while to load because of some simple jquery loop? Thanks for the link above, like that a lot

Comment: Yes, there might be a moment before the DOM loads, then JS, then a moment before it executes (adding classes to all elements), then another while to load the images. JS is not made for that what you're intending to do ;) Some kittens might cry.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is put all your icons into a single image, and have all the li elements belong to a class that uses that large image as the background. Then simply specify the background offset for each li.

This is a technique known as a sprite sheet - for more info read [AListApart:Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm kind of using this technique already for the hover and seeing the background-position. I have about 60 li elements so that would be one large image of 60 icons with 60 different states. and there are 3 states. Wow not ver efficient but I guess better than what I have already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to loop through all of the `li` elements in your page, and perform some action (this example prepends an image to each element):

```
$("li").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend("<img src='random.png' />");
});
```

However, if you need to add a different image to each element, I don't see how looping through them all is going to help you. If that's the case, what's wrong with your current method of using a long list of CSS classes?

**Update** Based on your comment, you could get the index of each `li` element and use it in the `src` attribute when adding the image:

```
$("li").each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).prepend("<img src='random" + index + ".png' />");
});
```

Comment: I was going to try and find the index of each element and tack on the index to the end of the image. This way as it loops through it would add the images sequential. example: icon_0, icon_1, icon_2 etc.. but people seem to think this is a slow method to use jquery. I thought it would be the most efficient, and efficiency usually means faster results.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was going to do. So this is a slow technique. Looks pretty straight forward to me and no sprite business. Why would this be slow, is it because you have to wait for the jquery files to load? or something else.